# Magento filter by attribute and category not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, category-attribute

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' => 26))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('trending',1)
     ->setPageSize(20);
```

This wont work when i use both  `->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' => 26))` and   `->addFieldToFilter('trending',1)`
if any one them are removed it will work

Comment: please review http://nwdthemes.com/2014/10/14/getting-products-by-attribute-or-category-in-magento/

Comment: I have tried these ways...I tried loading product collection from category model..When used attribute filter in this method no product will load... Next is loading product collection and filtering by category and attr if both cat & attr are filtered it wont work

Comment: You should be using `addAttributeToFilter` for the trending attribute